# How to pass parameters from makefile to Linux kernel module source code

Tags: linux, gcc, module, makefile, kernel

I have the source code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>   
#include <linux/kernel.h>   

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world %i\n", BUILD_NUMBER);
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

and a makefile:

```
obj-m += hello-1.o

BUILD_NUMBER := 42

# How to pass BUILD_NUMBER to hello-1.c ???

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Now how do I pass the BUILD_NUMBER parameter from the makefile to the source code?

Comment: is it your whole Makefile?

Comment: The makefile I want to use it for is larger, but the above is shortened for clarity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the Linux build system uses kernel provided Makefiles that can reasonably not be changed. I'd suggest to place your version number directly into the source code instead of in the Makefile.

There's a possibility thought. You can define a `CPPFLAGS` environment variable. It should be passed by the kernel Makefile to the C compiler command line. If you define this CPPFLAGS variable as `-DVERSION=42`, maybe you can use this `VERSION` macro inside your source file.

```
all:
    CPPFLAGS="-DVERSION=42" make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Note that `CPPFLAGS` stands for "C PreProcessor FLAGS". It is unrelated to C++.

After testing it. This does not work. There's a solution however. The kernel Makefile allows (and uses) the definition of the KCPPFLAGS environment variable that will be added to the kernel Makefile defined own CPPFLAGS.

You have to use:

```
all:
    KCPPFLAGS="-DVERSION=42" make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)
```

Comment: In addition to the BUILD_NUMBER I would also like to include a build date and time, which is not so convenient to have to alter manually directly in the source code.

Comment: Tho solution with `KCPPFLAGS` works. Use that to define your two macros with `KCPPFLAGS="-DVERSION=$(BUILD_NUMBER) -DDATE=$(shell date)"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using your answer, I also found that the following works: make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DBUILD_NUMBER=$(BUILD_NUMBER)" modules

Comment: To use the DATE, lots of shell escaping must be used, the following will define DATE as a string: KCPPFLAGS="-DDATE=\\\"\"$(shell date)\"\\\""

Comment: The KCPPFLAGS solution gives the warning: "WARNING: Appending $KCPPFLAGS ([cut out]) from environment to kernel $CPPFLAGS". The EXTRA_CFLAGS solution does not.

Comment: It is true that `KCPPFLAGS` gives a warning (which seem IMHO a good think), but at least it works. Using `EXTRA_CFLAGS` (or `EXTRA_CPPFLAGS`) does not work. The macro definition is not propagated to the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

On the command line, the right way of passing arguments to gcc according to the Kernel's [Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) is to set `CFLAGS_MODULE`.

For example, to build modules in the current directory with `BUILD_NUMBER=42`:

```
make CFLAGS_MODULE=-DBUILD_NUMBER=42 M="$PWD" modules
```

If you want to provide several `-D`, use single quotes:

```
make CFLAGS_MODULE='-DBUILD_NUMBER=42 -DSOME_OTHER_MACRO' M="$PWD" modules
```

Note: that's not limited to setting macros, for example you could use `CFLAGS_MODULE=-O0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
-DBUILD_NUMBER=$(BUILD_NUMBER)
```

To your compiler parameters. That should have the same effect as defining `BUILD_NUMBER` with a `#define` in your code.

Comment: No. `-D` something is a `gcc` command line argument, unknown by `make`.

Comment: Yep - thought of that myself - already changed it;) I've gotten too used to cmake apparently...

Comment: The compiler parameters are not given here, in this Makefile. It's not that easy!